# Grails: encoding for BootStrap.groovy class

Tags: grails, encoding, groovy, bootstrapping

I have a domain class 'Article' and want to populate my application with example instances of that class from BootStrap.groovy. I call the following code (just a simplified example):

```
Article article1 = new Article(title: "New article", content: "äöäööü€€€££$")
article1.save(failOnError: true)
```

...and it saves the article but some of the symbols will be saved (and rendered) as questionmarks ("?")

When i create an article instance from a running application via a form and a command in ArticleController, then all the symbols are saved properly into the database and rendered properly in the views. The problem isn't in the GSP's encodings nor in database settings.

When debugging the bootstrap class, i see that after article1 is created (even before saving), all the problematic symbols have already been replaced with questionmarks.

So why is BootStrap.groovy interpreting "äöäööü€€€££$" as "????????????" ? 
Should i create the initial domain instances with BootStrap.groovy or use some other way?

Grails version: 2.3.6, OS: windows

Thanks.

Comment: What is the default encoding your IDE is using?

Comment: This might help, if you aren't using an IDE: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/charset-in-BootStrap-groovy-td3046493.html

Comment: Hey, sorry for not specifying the IDE part. I am using Groovy/Grails Tool Suite's newest version. 

I did set text-file encoding (window-preferences-general-workspace) from Default (Cp1257) to UTF-8, but nothing changed. Not even after grails-clean+deleting the target-folders. Are there any other encodings i can set somewhere in the tool-suite?

Comment: It could be an encoding problem in GGTS. You can force the default encoding to be UTF-8 by adding a line -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to the GGTS.ini file after the -vmargs line in that file. GGTS.ini file is in the GGTS installation directory (same directory as GGTS.exe?).

Comment: Your BootStrap.groovy file might be in Cp1252 encoding and perhaps Eclipse autodetects the encoding even if you change the default to UTF-8. Try recreating the file when UTF-8 is the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! Recreating the bootstrap class helped. I recreated it having changed the GGTS.ini file and it worked. I also wanted to know whether recreating it without changes to the GGTS.ini would have worked, so i tried it that way too.

And it worked both ways, so the solution is to recreate the BootStrap.groovy file after having changed text-file-encoding to UTF-8.

Thanks to FlareCoder!